# Given a fixed-length integer array arr, duplicate each occurrence of zero, shift elements to right

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Dupzero {
    static int dup =0;
    
    public static void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
        //read all the elememts in arrays
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i]==0) {
            for(int j=arr.length-2;j>=i;j--) {
                arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                
            }
            i=i+1;
        
        }
         
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []arr = {
                1,0,2,3,0,4,5,0 
        };
    duplicateZeros(arr);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code and i get expected output. Previously i was getting wrong output as i missed the statement i=i+1; .. Can you explain me here in the code what is i=i+1 doing ? is it in the right place ?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 0):

`i = i+1` increments the counter of the outer for-loop by 1.  When you copy a `0` to the right you need to ignore that copied `0` value as you continue to step through.  Otherwise, you will just fill out the array with `0`s.

Is it in the right place?  Well, you say its working so it seems to be.  Write some tests to verify the expected behavior.